# How to get a job as a game programmer/developer in AAA studios?

Tags: jobs

I have looked up and down on the internet and haven't really found the solution, or maybe I am just too confused to know the answer.

I love games and wanted to get into making them from a long time. I first started working with Unity and then realized that I could not see how this could help me in getting into AAA studios as all there job requirements had stuff that I didn't learn in the process. Then it felt like making a game engine would help me learn better what those studios want. But then that stuff was too overwhelmingly tough for me to actually get something competitive done. I did learn some things, but it was not a one man job. 
I then again decided to go into making games on a pre-existing engine, this time I took up Unreal Engine 4. But this time I have a better idea of what I want to do. I am interested in making game play logic, AI system, and on a side have fair bit of interest in modelling (not texturing) and animation. I may not be good at all this right now, but I have figured out what I have to do exactly, and on the side. 
Now again I did end up one some companies job page(Naughty Dog, Santa Monica and Sucker Punch) and I found myself in the sea of confusion and hopelessness, half of the time I couldn't figure out what the requirements.

So my question is, is learning how to get complex AI running in UE4, setting up some nice game play mechanics in UE4, and setting up a nice UI in UE4 and creating some models and animating them in Maya will be enough to get me a job at some of the AAA studios I mentioned?

I know I haven't done all the stuff I mentioned in depth, but I can't proceed without having a proper aim and path, the path can change in between but should lead me somewhere at least.

I will be thankful for any good advice.

Edit. I am not good at art, just in case.

Answer (score 3):

Lower your expectations. Getting a job at a studio like Naughty Dog without having worked in the industry for quite some time is unrealistic. And don't try to become Jack of all trades unless you want to run your own one man indie studio. Try to focus on one specific area and master it. Then try to get a foot in the door by looking at smaller studios first.

Answer (score 1):

Easy: working hard.

AAA Studios want people highly specialized in some specific areas, like model of environments or lighting.

Comment: So much this!  Most developers working in a big studio have very singular, specialized skills: AI, pathing, crafting system design, environments, characters, story progression, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, every game mechanics programmer needs to know about 3D mathematics, and ability to program with engines/languages. So "get complex AI running in UE4, setting up some nice game play mechanics in UE4, and setting up a nice UI in UE4 and creating some models and animating them in Maya" can be enough to work at studios.

But in AAA studios, things can go a little bit different. They need not only those who can do above stuffs, but also the best ones - with experience and has a vital role in some released titles.

So this is my advice for you (and for me, too, since I found myself in you, even the path we experienced, the feelings we had when see an AAA studio's job requirements,...): find a job in a small studios - gain more experience. Then you will know what need to be done next.